# How to filter a table field's listbox by the current record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I set up a table's field so that the listbox is filtered by that row's data?

I have a master table (**TblMain**) with 2 important fields: **Client** and **Division**.  Currently, the Division field is set up as a simple Listbox that pulls from another table (**TblDiv**).

However, the Divisions are specific to each client with little overlap.  My current basic setup doesn't make that distinction, so any division can be chosen for any client.

How do I set up Division so that the listbox is specific to that row?

I've tried doing an inner join within the row source (i.e. `Select TblDiv.Div from TblMain Inner Join TblDiv on TblMain.Client=TblDiv.Client`) but that doesn't seem to work, probably because I'm not referencing the Client value of the active row.

(I should add I'm not talking about Forms or Reports. Just the Table object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to add a look-up field to a table? This is almost never a good idea. Are you trying to filter a combobox on a continuous form? You cannot sensibly do this - any change will affect the appearance of every row, which is confusing to the user. There are work-arounds. For example, you can show a textbox for the Reference and a "Change reference" combo. This will avoid confusing users because the bound textbox will not update. You can set various properties of the change combo with conditional formatting to make it all prettier. Alternatively, you can use two subforms or a pop-up form to edit data.

Comment: I am trying to add a look-up field to a table.  Because this project is still in flux, I'm trying to avoid making a nice looking Form and just adding some basic functionality to the table itself.

Comment: I suggest you keep functionality for the form. If it is a database design issue, it may be possible to work with a junction table.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll just leave this functionality for the nice looking Form then.